# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProduitController::show()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I wants to show users list into my dashboard pannel but it shows me this problem :

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProduitController::show(), 0 passed in C:\wamp64\www\Ecommerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected
```

Controller File :

```
public function show($id)
{   
    $produit = Produit::find($id);
    return view('produits', compact('produit'));
}
```

blade file :

```
@foreach($produits as $produit)
    <div class="product__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="{{ asset('img/uploads/'.$produit->image)}}">
        <ul class="product__item__pic__hover">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="product__item__text">
        <h6><a href="#">{{ $produit->designation }}</a></h6>
        <h5>{{ $produit->prix_uni }} Mad</h5>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/produits','ProduitController@show');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an id in your function definition, this should also be there in route definition. Route variables is defined with `{id}`.

```
Route::get('/produits/{id}','ProduitController@show');
```

For a best practice, use model binding, if you call your route variable the same as the model, you can automatically load it by typehinting it.

```
Route::get('/produits/{produit}','ProduitController@show');

public function show(Produit $produit)
```